# rails 4.0 explain the syntax -> in association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can someone help me to understand the below syntax ?

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders, -> { order "date_confirmed DESC" }
end
```

what is this -> symbol after :orders doing? I don't understand this symbol here? Please elaborate.

please refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It is query to the database.

Due to this you can have in your CustomersController something like:

```
Customer.find(1).orders.order(date_confirmated)
```

which will be translated to SQL as:

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY date_confirmated DESC
```

You will find complete explanation of this at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Concretely this syntax "->" is for proc. What's the Proc (if you need this) you'll find here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html